# PySide2 - QStyledItemDelegate: Get back default text interaction

Tags: python-3.x, pyside2

I wanted to know if it is possible to recover the default interaction with the text after painting it in a delegate.
For example, I paint a delegate that renders markdown, but I can't select it anymore, or click on the links etc.
I haven't really found (or searched for) any information about this.
I use PySide2.

example on how I paint the text in the QStyledItemDelegate paint method:

```py
width = option.rect.right() - left - DELEGATE.BORDER_H_SPACE

doc = QTextDocument()

doc.setMarkdown(msg)
doc.setDefaultFont(option.font)  # fonts will be correct when you change them via stylesheet
doc.setDocumentMargin(0)  # left space
doc.setTextWidth(width)

painter.save()

painter.translate(left, top)

clip = QRectF(0, 0, width, option.rect.height())
painter.setClipRect(clip)
ctx = QAbstractTextDocumentLayout.PaintContext()
ctx.palette.setColor(QPalette.Text, painter.pen().color())  # set text color
ctx.clip = clip
doc.documentLayout().draw(painter, ctx)

painter.restore()
```

Thank you in advance for your answers!

Comment: The `paint()` function only does what its name says: it *paints*. If you wanted selectable text, you should override [`createEditor()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleditemdelegate.html#createEditor) and return a QTextEdit.